# Trying to optimize sass breakpoint mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I created a simple mixin for dealing with some media queries that I have working but would love to output the min and max values with whats in the map. I am having trouble with the max width as it should be the value after the first and so on. I currently have it working without the @each loop and using a get map value function. I might be over complicating this.

**For example**
@media (min-width:**first val in map**) and (max-width:**next val in map**)

```
$breakpoints: (
    small: 0,
    medium: 640px,
    large: 1024px
);

@mixin breakpoint($point) {
  @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
  @media (min-width:nth($breakpoint, 2)) and (max-width:next-size)) { @content; }
 }
}
```

**The output css should be:**

```
@media (min-width: 0) and (max-width: 640px) {}
@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1024px) {}
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to first get the key of the next breakpoint inside the each loop and then get the value by using map-get

```
$breakpoints: (
    small: 0,
    medium: 640px,
    large: 1024px
);

@mixin breakpoint() {
  @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {

    $i: index($breakpoints, $breakpoint);

    @if $i < 3 {      
       $nextKey: nth(map-keys($breakpoints), $i+1);
       @media (min-width:nth($breakpoint, 2)) and (max-width:map-get($breakpoints,$nextKey)) { @content; }      
    }    
 }
}
@include breakpoint() {
    width: 50%;
}
```